# Firebase - How to check if a subcollection is not null or empty on a where clause?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```js
this.db
      .collection("titles")
      .orderBy("name")
      .where("usernames", "!=", null);
```

I'm aware that Firebase doesn't support `!=` operator. So, how to check if `usernames` *(it's a subcollection)* is not null (or empty)?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm aware that Firebase doesn't support != operator.

Yes, that's right.

> So, how to check if usernames (it's a subcollection) is not null (or empty)?

You cannot check if `usernames` is a subcollection using a `where()` function. What you can do instead is to check the number of documents within your `usernames` subcollection:

```
this.db.collection('titles').doc('titleId').get().then(
  doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      this.db.collection('titles').doc('titleId').collection('usernames').limit(1).get().
        then(sub => {
          if (sub.docs.length > 0) {
            console.log('usernames subcollection exists!');
          }
        });
      }
  });
```

So the solution is to check if `docs.length > 0`.

Besides that, a subcollection cannot be `null`, nor empty. If a collection does not contain any documents, it does not exist at all.

Comment: When checking for existence please **always** add a `limit(1)` to the query, to prevent retrieving more documents than needed.