# How to perform a check for a particular FirebaseFirestore error code?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code:

```
db.collection("property").document(userUID).update(propertyRoot).addOnSuccessListener(
                new OnSuccessListener<Void>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                    {
                        //Success
                    }
                }
        ).addOnFailureListener(
                new OnFailureListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e){
                        //Create a new collection and set
                    }
                }
        );
```

I would like to update my Firestore database if the collection already exists. Otherwise, I would like Firestore to create a new collection.

I would like to create a new collection only if the collection is not found. Essentially, I would like to do the check like this:

```
db.collection("property").document(userUID).update(propertyRoot).addOnSuccessListener(
                    new OnSuccessListener<Void>(){
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                        {
                            //Success
                        }
                    }
            ).addOnFailureListener(
                    new OnFailureListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e){
                            if(e.errorCode == FirebaseFirestoreException.NOT_FOUND)
                            {
                                //Create a new collection and set
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
```

How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60670969/firebase-how-to-check-if-a-subcollection-is-not-null-or-empty-on-a-where-claus) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be possible if you cast the exception to a [`feedbackFirebaseFirestoreException`  object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException) and then check its `getCode()` value against the possible [Firestore error codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code).

So something like:

```
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e){
  if (e is FirebaseFirestoreException) {
    if ((e as FirebaseFirestoreException).getCode() == FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.NOT_FOUND)
    {
        //Create a new collection and set
    }
  }
}
```