# How to receive additional information by using firebase in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

When the user signs up the first time, I use `sendEmailVerification` by the following code:

```
 FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            String uid = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
                            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                            mFirebaseUser.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        startToast("Plz go to your mail box.");
                                        UserAccount account = new UserAccount(uid, strEmail, strPwd);
                                        db.collection("Basic_users").document(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).set(account).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void avoid) {
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        })
                                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                        startToast("failed to register");
                                                    }
                                                });
```

and here is useAccount.java

```
public class UserAccount {
    private String idToken; 
    private String strEmail;
    private String strPwd;

    public void setIdToken(String idToken) {
        this.idToken = idToken;
    }

    public void setStrEmail(String strEmail) {
        this.strEmail = strEmail;
    }

    public void setStrPwd(String strPwd) {
        this.strPwd = strPwd;
    }

    public String getIdToken() {
        return idToken;
    }

    public String getStrEmail() {
        return strEmail;
    }

    public String getStrPwd() {
        return strPwd;
    }

    public UserAccount(String idToken, String strEmail, String strPwd) {
        this.idToken = idToken;
        this.strEmail = strEmail;
        this.strPwd = strPwd;
    }
```

[Firebase information after signing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgKW9.png)

and as you can see All the information was received accurately. 
But I want to receive additional information when user first use the app.
SO i tried to receive additional info by following code

```
  FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user == null) { //IF there's no user information go to registerActiviety
            startActivity(registerActivity.class);
        } else { //else get current user information
            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(user.getUid());
            docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        if (document.exists()) { //if document exist
                            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                        } else { //else go to MemberinitActivity and receive some 
                                 //additional information
                            Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                            startActivity(MemberinitActivity.class);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

and this is memberinfo.java, which has information that i want to receive more.

```
public class MemberInfo
{
private String idToken; 
private String name;
private String birthday;
private String address;
private String phone_number;

public MemberInfo(String idToken, String name, String birthday,String 
phone_number,String address) {
        this.idToken = idToken;
        this.name = name;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setIdToken(String idToken) {
        this.idToken = idToken;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) {
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
    }

    public String getIdToken() {
        return idToken;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getPhone_number() {
        return phone_number;
    }
}
```

After checking the log, I found that the program recognized the document as being present
but it actually has nothing(null)
[log of "if document exists"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTV5p.png)

I think the program was confused since they share the same `getcurrentuser()`
How can I separate two user values and receive additional information?

Comment: What data do you have stored in `users`? You haven't shown the code where you stored "user" data.

Comment: @AliasCartellano As you can see i stored IDTOKEN,EMAIL,AND PASSWORD in userAccount.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think the program was confused since they share the same getcurrentuser()

No, that's not the reason why you aren't getting any data. The problem in your code lies in the fact that you're writing the data to Firestore at the following location:

```
db.collection("Basic_users").document(mFirebaseUser.getUid())
                //
```

But you are trying to read from a different location:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(user.getUid());
                                         //
```

Since your screenshot indicates that the user exists under the `Basic_users` collection, to solve the issue, please change the last line of code to:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Basic_users").document(user.getUid());
                                           //
```

Comment: I have some problems. Since I want to save information different collections, which are Basic_users and users I think i have to use `DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(user.getUid());` . If i try to read from "basic_users" collections ,since i was received some basic informations by using `sendEmailVerification` , Documents are bound to exist. Therefore, activity will not move to MemberinitActivity . Am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, since you aren't getting any data, in other words, the document doesn't exist, your activity doesn't start.

Comment: then how can i receive more informations even "basic_users" are 
existed? Since they won't move to MemberinitActivity, I cannot receive more informations

Comment: If want to check if a collection already exists, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60670969/firebase-how-to-check-if-a-subcollection-is-not-null-or-empty-on-a-where-claus).